# Specificity issue with IDs and media querys

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-specificity

I am having some trouble with CSS, when i try the site on a mobile device the line height remains at 65px , this can be fixed by putting a !important in front but this is not the kind of fix i want, should i be using a class or something?

Thank you very much

```
/*Change the glyph size when necessary*/
@media only screen and (max-width:990px)
{

    #IEGlyphPlacement 
    {
        line-height: 80px;
    }

}


#Glyph 
{
    line-height: 65px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're targeting a different element inside of the media query. The media query is targeting the element with an ID of `IEGlyphPlacement`, rather than `Glyph` (which you define in the non-media query code).

Update as follows:

```
/*Change the glyph size when necessary*/
@media only screen and (max-width:990px)
{

    #Glyph 
    {
        line-height: 80px;
    }

}


#Glyph 
{
    line-height: 65px;
}
```

Comment: ah yes, sorry that was just an issue when i took out what i thought was irrelevant code, here is a bit more info if you can crack it

http://i.imgur.com/Z2ka8xn.png

could you explain why that line-height in teh media query is crossed out?

Comment: It is crossed out because media queries are less specific than generic ID selectors. Try updating the media query's selector to `body #Glyph`.